# Como renderizar JComboBox para que muestre un regex especifico

Tags: java, mysql, regex, hibernate

mo pregunta es **¿como puedo pasar de esto?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**a esto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un JCombobox el cual renderizo con la interface **ListCellRenderer** para que me muestre ciertos datos en el mismo. Lo que sucede es que los datos origonales sin renderizar son mostrados asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quiero mostrarlos como se ven en la segunda imagen. Para eso hago un regex de la siguiente manera:

```
public class RenderizadoJComboBox implements ListCellRenderer {

    private DefaultListCellRenderer defaultRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

    @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            JLabel jLabel = (JLabel) defaultRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            if (value instanceof Cardios) {
                String cadena = String.valueOf(value.toString());
                String cadenaModificada = cadena.replaceAll("[.0&&[^0-9]]", " Min - ");
                jLabel.setText(cadenaModificada);
            }

            return jLabel;
        }
    }
```

Pero no logro hacer que me muestre lo que deseo ya que la salida es

**2 Min - 0 Moderado**

Lo cual cel **0(cero)** no iria, en todos los datos me muestra lo mismo. Si cambio el regex a:

```
String cadenaModificada = cadena.replaceAll(".0", " Min - ");
```

La salida que obtengo es para **algúnos** números es correcta **pero** para números como el 10 20 30 etc, el resultado es

**Min -  Min -  Moderado**

No soy muy bueno en los regex, agradeceria mucho su ayuda, alguna sujerencia o lo que sea en lo que le este errando. Desde ya gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿todos los datos que vas a mostrar deseas quitarle la parte decimal o sólo deseas quitar la parte decimal que sea igual a cero? Porque si es lo primero, no necesitas un `regexp`.

Comment: Analizando bien, creo que no necesitas un `regexp` para nada. Usando un `indexof` y un `substring` puedes esxtraer la parte correspondiente al número que deseas mostrar y le concatenas el resto. ¿Has probado eso?

Comment: para clarificar, puedes añadir una lista de cadenas y como deberian ser convertidas correctamente? tambien añade casos incorrectos. mira [mcve] para más info. Un saludo!

Comment: @MauricioContreras sólo deseo quitar la parde decimal, que muestre sólo la parte entera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu segunda aproximación iba bien encaminada, pero la expresión regular tenía un pequeño error. El punto se debe escapar así `\\.` o así `[.]` ya que en caso contrario significa `cualquier caracter excepto salto de línea`.

En cuyo caso al buscar `.0` en la siguiente cadena, por ejemplo: `10.0 Moderado`, tienes dos ocurrencias:

1. La primera es: `10` (el punto encuentra el 1 y el 0 encuentra el 0)
2. La segunda es: `.0`
3. Al remplazar ambas por `Min -` es normal que aparezca dos veces

Así pues, lo siguiente debería funcionar:

```
String cadenaModificada = cadena.replaceAll("[.]0", " Min -");
```

Tienes una demo [aquí](https://ideone.com/eRzGyd)

Comment: genio total! Muchas gracias de verdad! Funciono correctamente